# Cannot convert NULL value to non-Nullable type:While executing S3. (CANNOT_INSERT_NULL_IN_ORDINARY_COLUMN

Tags: parquet, clickhouse

I tried to insert data from parquet file with this code:

```
INSERT INTO general_marts.gm_order
SELECT *
FROM s3(
'http://host:9000/general-marts/general_mart_order/year=2024/month=02/day=12/*.snappy.parquet',
'aws_access_key_id',
'aws_secret_access_key','Parquet');
```

General Mart Order Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE general_marts.gm_order
(
    order_id                      Int64,
    user_id                       Int64,
    vendor_id                     Int64,
    total_price                   Int64,
    total_price_after_discount    Int64,
    payable_price                 Int64,
    customer_name                 String,
    vendor_name                   String,
    preparation_time              Int32,
    delivery_type                 Nullable(String),
    accepted_at Nullable(DateTime64(3)),
    nfc_reason Nullable(String),
    rejected_at Nullable(DateTime64(3)),
    paid_at Nullable(DateTime64(3)),
    created_at DateTime64(3),
    list_order_status Array(String),
    list_order_status_datetime Array(DateTime64(3)),
    list_payment_status Array(String),
    list_payment_status_datetime Array(DateTime64(3)),
    list_delivery_status Array(String),
    list_delivery_status_datetime  Array(DateTime64(3)),
    voucher_id Nullable(String),
    voucher_name Nullable(String),
    voucher_code Nullable(String),
    voucher_value Nullable(Int64),
    ofood_share_delivery_price    Int64,
    customer_share_delivery_price Int64,
    vendor_share_delivery_price   Int64,
    delivery_order_id Nullable(Int64),
    packing_price                 Int64,
    vendor_tax                    Int64,
    refund_at Nullable(DateTime64(3)),
    refund_amount Nullable(Int64),
    city_name Nullable(String),
    list_product_id Array(String),
    list_product_name Array(String),
    list_product_variation_id Array(String),
    list_product_variation_name Array(String),
    list_option_ids Array(Array(String)),
    list_options Array(Array(String)),
    list_option_label Array(Nullable(String)),
    list_has_option Array(String),
    list_price Array(String),
    list_price_after_discount Array(String),
    list_quantity Array(String),
    list_stock Array(String),
    list_capacity Array(String))
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY order_id;
```

But i got this Error :

```
Code: 349. DB::Exception: Cannot convert NULL value to non-Nullable type: while converting column accepted_at from type Nullable(UInt32) to type UInt32: While executing ParquetBlockInputFormat: While executing S3. (CANNOT_INSERT_NULL_IN_ORDINARY_COLUMN) (version 22.2.2.1)
```

I use Spark to write a Parquet file into Minio, and then I attempt to read it using the S3 engine in ClickHouse, but I encounter an error.

It appears the issue arises from columns containing 'None' values in the Parquet file. However, it's worth noting that other columns in this file, which have default values such as an empty string (''), 0, or a specific date ('2022-01-01'), are processed without any problems.

I prefer not to replace missing values in the columns ('fill na'). Instead, I would like ClickHouse to display these columns with their null values intact.

Comment: Can you try on a supported version? 22.2 is very old.
Also are you inserting into a table i.e. INSERT INTO SELECT ?

Comment: @gingerwizard I updated question , please check it again , and my clickhouse version is 22.2.2.1 , Thank you

Comment: I checked Release Note here and it support s3: 
https://clickhouse.com/blog/clickhouse-22-2-released#control-of-file-creation-and-rewriting-on-data-export-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem just for version of clickhouse, i updated clickhouse to version 22.6.1.1985 and it works.

Comment: better upgrade to 22.8 in this case